# Using Java reflection class to create an object and use it in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, reflection

I started to use Java Reflection recently but currently stuck at this.

So I have something like this:

```
Class<?> dogClass = Class.forName("com.example.dog");
Object dogObject = dogClass.newInstance();
```

I would like to use the above object in this arraylist:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList();
```

So in normal case:

```
for(Dog d : dogList) {
....
.... 
}
```

But when I tried to use the java reflection, it doesn't work..

```
for(dogObject d : dogList) {
....
.... 
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me please? Thank you.

Comment: Use like this.    for(Object d : dogList){   }

Comment: The `for` loop iterates over the objects already existing in the list. Where is the relationship to the new object you’ve just created? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

`for(dogObject d : dogList)` is wrong. `dogObject` is an object and not a type. add your `dogObject` to `dogList` and then loop it like you do in the first loop:

```
Class<?> dogClass = Class.forName("com.example.Dog");
Dog dogObject = (Dog)dogClass.newInstance();
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
dogList.add(dogObject);
for (Dog dog : dogList) {
   ....         
}
```

(and you need to add try/catch of course)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of foreach loop is like below

```
for(T Obj: Objects) {
....
.... 
}
```

but in your code you are using **Obj** in-place of ***T*** (Object Type). It's wrong way of coding for each loop. in your code **dogObject** is instance of reflection class ***dogClass*** so java will throw compile error.